# Custom 301 rule for redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have link like this:
www.my-site.com/full-image/folder/subfolder/image-name.jpg-some-custom-keywords.html

and I need 301 redirection to url like this:

www.my-site.com/folder/subfolder/image-name.jpg.html?some-custom-keywords.html

I need to remove "**full-image/**" and to change "**.jpg-**" to "**.jpg.html?**"

I managed to write url redirection to remove "full-image/" like this:

RewriteRule ^full-image/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

By the way is this rewrite rule best way? (it works)

But how to change "**.jpg-**" to "**.jpg.html?**"

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^full-image/(.+?\.jpg)-(.*)$ /$1.html?$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Firstly I get 500 Error, then I changed a little your rewrite code and it is working now. RewriteRule ^full-image/(.*).jpg-(.*)$ /$1.jpg.html?$2 [L,R=301]